# Horizontal Flip Transform in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was wondering what is the best way to flip an element horizontally in silverlight.

What I've tried so far:

1- Scale transformation: the problem this approach has is that I need to hardcode the width of the element to translate it after setting scale=-1; this makes it hard to implement (for many elements)

```
    <ScaleTransform CenterX="240" ScaleX="-1" />
```

2- Plane projection: the problem with this one is that even mouse gestures are reversed! this makes it so impossible to use.

```
    <PlaneProjection RotationY="-180" />
```

[NOTE] By reversed mouse gesture I mean: when applying plane projection, then dragging mouse to left is interpreted as dragging to right and vice versa.

Any suggestion? Or is there anyway in (1) to say CenterX="50%" ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set `<uiElement RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>`. Your scale transform will not need translation after that.

Comment: this has the same reversed mouse problem :( do u know a workaround for that? (read question, I explained about reversal)